# Can we create a smart TV by using set top box, a monitor and raspberry Pi?

Tags: television-tuner

Can we use set top box (e.g. Dish TV or TATA Sky) and a LCD monitor for display and raspberry Pi to connect these two? TV tuner card can be used to connect set top box to the laptop to watch tv on laptop screen. Is it possible to replace laptop with raspberry pi?

Answer (score 2):

OSMC support things like this. You can use TV tuner cards, as long as it has driver. If you use a setup like this, the set top box becames unneccesary, the TV tuner card replaces it. You can check what standard is used on your broadcasting method (like DVB-C), buy a compatible tuner, then use it with your Pi. For further information google for "osmc dvb-s", etc.. there are a lot of information and experience on the osmc forums.

About DVB:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Video_Broadcasting

You can check linux compatibility here: 
https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/DVB-S2_USB_Devices